# C - Find a word and get the next two

Tags: c, string, char

I am parsing a file in C, line by line. Here is an exemple of what I am trying to do :

I have a line for example :
`word word word WORDTOFIND: word1 word2 word word`

What I want to do is : When I find the word `WORDTOFIND`, get the two next words (`word1` and `word2` in this case) of the line. Is there an easy way to do that in C ? I know about the **strstr** function, but I don't find a way to get the next two words `word1` and `word2` after I found the good one.

Comment: One way would be to parse the line into an array of words making it easy to know what/if the next two words are.  This is slightly more expensive that alternative approaches, however.

Comment: So you would want to get `word1` and `word2` in this case? Please be more specific in the question, or show some examples.

Comment: I edited the post, sorry if I wasn't clear. Yes I want the word1 and word2 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *str = "rated rat cat bat hat";
    char *key = "rat ";
    char *pointer = NULL;
    char nwords = 2;

    if ((pointer = strstr(str, key)) != NULL)
    {
        while (*pointer != ' ') pointer++;
        while (nwords >= 0)
        {
            printf("%c", *pointer);
            if (*pointer == ' ') {
                nwords--;
            } else if (*pointer == '\0') {
                exit(0);
            }

            pointer++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is very simplistic. What if there is "rated" before "rat"? What if words are separated by more than one blank or. as in the question, by punctuation? Worst of all, this code tries to read beyond the original string if fewer than two words follow the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an aproach like this, using [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse the words at every space. This code also uses [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) and [`realloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to allocate space for an array of strings, and grows it when needed.

The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXCHAR 100

void exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg);
char *stripped_word(char *word);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    FILE *filename;
    char line[MAXCHAR];
    char *word, *newword;
    char **allwords;
    int init_size = 8, count = 0, i;
    const char *key = "WORDTOFIND";

    filename = fopen("files.txt", "r");

    if (filename == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    allwords = malloc(init_size * sizeof(*allwords));
    exit_if_null(allwords, "Initial Allocation");

    while (fgets(line, MAXCHAR, filename) != NULL) {
        word = strtok(line, " \n");

        while (word != NULL) {
            if (count == init_size) {
                init_size *= 2;
                allwords = realloc(allwords, init_size * sizeof(*allwords));
            }

            allwords[count] = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
            exit_if_null(allwords[count], "Initial Allocation");

            newword = stripped_word(word);

            strcpy(allwords[count], newword);

            count++;

            word = strtok(NULL, " \n");

            free(newword);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(key, allwords[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Next two words:\n");
            printf("%s\n", allwords[i+1]);
            printf("%s\n", allwords[i+2]);
        } 
        free(allwords[i]);
        allwords[i] = NULL;
    }

    free(allwords);
    allwords = NULL;

    return 0;
}

void
exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg) {
    if (!ptr) {
        printf("Unexpected null pointer: %s\n", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

char
*stripped_word(char *word) {
    int i, pos = 0;
    char *result;

    result = malloc(strlen(word)+1);
    exit_if_null(result, "Initial Allocation");

    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalpha(word[i]) || isdigit(word[i])) {
            result[pos++] = word[i];
        }
    }

    result[pos] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```